# I was trying to print array indexes , but how do we do it in reverse order in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting

```
<tr ng-repeat="qualityalert in qualityalerts" current="$parent.start;$parent.start=$parent.start+(qualityalerts.length);">
<td class="v-middle">{{current + $index}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Note:** This is one which I was referring to, but I want array indexes in reverse order in angular js.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't want to reverse my array , as I am printing array indexes, I just want to reverse them not the whole array using orderBy filter. was referring this in the whole context http://jsfiddle.net/rvgvs2jt/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="AppController">
 <table class="friends">
  <tr>
   <th>Order</th><th>Name<th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Age</th>
  </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="(k,friend) in friends| orderBy:'-' ">
    <td>{{friends.length - $index}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>


app=angular.module('myapp', [])
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.friends = [
  {name: 'John',   phone: '555-1212',  age: 10},
  {name: 'Mary',   phone: '555-9876',  age: 19},
  {name: 'Mike',   phone: '555-4321',  age: 21},
  {name: 'Adam',   phone: '555-5678',  age: 35},
  {name: 'Julie',  phone: '555-8765',  age: 29}
 ];
}]);
```

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/tojopaul/og09Lr65/4/)

check with this.I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Click the table headers to change the sorting order:</p>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Name</th>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('country')">Country</th>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('newIndex')">Index</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:myOrderBy:true" ng-init="x.newIndex = $index">
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>{{x.country}}</td>
<td>{{x.newIndex}}</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Margareth',country:'England'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Mary',country:'England'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Norway'}
        ];
    $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {
        $scope.myOrderBy = x;
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example to illustrate iteration to reverse

```
<div ng-repeat="qualityalert in qualityalerts track by $index | orderBy:'-toString()'">
    {{$index}}
</div>
```

Comment: I feel this might work please check the below link , i was referring for this code snippet all the time for printing numbers http://jsfiddle.net/rvgvs2jt/2/

Comment: yeah it works, but i think he want to print the indexs in reverse